# Run mysql query that is running in command line in the background

Tags: mysql, background-process

I have executed a stored procedure in mysql command line prompt, i need to make it run at the background. So that even if i logged out from the VM, query can run at the background.

I saw few options, but all of them are before logging into mysql command prompt, not for the already started queries.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database event and schedule this procedure over there so even if you logged out from your VM, it will keep running on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm looking to make currently executing query/procedure. Something similar to unix scripts, how we make it to run foreground and background.